# 32 bit process receiving messages but not executing them

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard, 32bit-64bit, com-interop

I'm trying to send some keystrokes to an external 32 bit process using `PostMessage` :

```
class WindowHook
{
    const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);

    public static void SendKeystroke(char c, int processId)
    {
        var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        var hwdn = process.MainWindowHandle;

        SendCharacter(c, hwdn);
    }

    private static void SendCharacter(char character, IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        var k = (uint)(int)ConvertCharToVirtualKey(character);

        uint repeatCount = 1;
        uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey(k, 0);
        uint extended = 0;
        uint context = 0;
        uint previousState = 0;
        uint transition = 0;

        var lParamDown = repeatCount
                          | (scanCode << 16)
                          | (extended << 24)
                          | (context << 29)
                          | (previousState << 30)
                          | (transition << 31);

        previousState = 1;
        transition = 1;

        var lParamUp = repeatCount
                        | (scanCode << 16)
                        | (extended << 24)
                        | (context << 29)
                        | (previousState << 30)
                        | (transition << 31);

        var ipKey = (IntPtr)(int)k;
        var ipLParamDown = unchecked((IntPtr)(int)lParamDown);
        var ipLParamUp = unchecked((IntPtr)(int)lParamUp);

        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, ipKey, ipLParamDown);
        var random = new Random().Next(50, 100);
        Thread.Sleep(random);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, ipKey, ipLParamUp);
    }

    private static Keys ConvertCharToVirtualKey(char ch)
    {
        var vkey = VkKeyScan(ch);
        var retval = (Keys)(vkey & 0xff);
        var modifiers = vkey >> 8;
        if ((modifiers & 1) != 0) retval |= Keys.Shift;
        if ((modifiers & 2) != 0) retval |= Keys.Control;
        if ((modifiers & 4) != 0) retval |= Keys.Alt;
        return retval;
    }
}
```

The messages completely match the ones generated by actual keypresses as proven by spy++, the handle is correct, but the messages are not being processed or rather they are not doing anything.

[image]

The first 3 lines are the ones generated by my program and the last 3 are the ones generated by pressing the same key on the keyboard manually.

I've also tried `SendKeys.Send/Wait`, those do work but not very reliably, their clicks are also being displayed in the handle messages in spy++, however if a message is sent every 10 ms, only about 1 is being processed every 1000 ms, so a success rate of about 1/100.

Both calls to `PostMessage` return true and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returns 0.

My program is running on 64 bit OS, with option 'prefer 32-bit' set. The target software is 20-25 years old and is a 32 bit process.

Comment: And you can confirm, that the first three messages captured by spy++ do not provoke any response in the "other" application but the latter three messages do? You did not change the active window or anything else, right?

Comment: The other application was always on focus when the messages were sent. And there was no visible response. The scancodes match so the exact same key must've been sent, meaning there shouldn't be another action triggering in it's place.